# Weighted count of Egyptian fraction representations

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recreational-mathematics, egyptian-fractions

*This question emerged during an activity I ran for some middle school students a couple weeks ago; basically, it's about a way to "count" - with an appropriate kind of weight - the Egyptian fraction representations of a given rational.*

Let $[\mathbb{N}]^{\mathit{fin}}$ denote the set of finite sets of natural numbers. Given a positive rational $q$, let $\mathsf{E}(q)=\{X\in[\mathbb{N}]^{\mathit{fin}}: q=\sum_{x\in X}{1\over x}\}$ be the set of [Egyptian fraction representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction) (without duplication!) of $q$. For example, $\mathsf{E}(1)$ contains both $\{1\}$ and $\{2,3,6\}$, as well as infinitely many other finite sets.

I'm interested in the function $$\mathscr{E}: q\mapsto \sum_{X\in \mathsf{E}(q)} \left( \prod_{x\in X}{1\over x}\right).$$ Intuitively, I'm trying to count the Egyptian fraction representations of $q$; of course this is infinite regardless of what $q$ is (since ${1\over n}={1\over n+1}+{1\over n^2+n}$), but I'm tweaking things to pay more attention to "short" representations with "small" denominators.

In general, $\mathscr{E}$'s behavior seems rather complicated. I have an outline of an argument that $\mathscr{E}(q)$ is indeed finite for all $q$, but I'm not entirely certain it's correct; even if it is correct, anything more than that is unclear to me, including its behavior on specific values. So my two questions are:

> **Question 1**: What is $\mathscr{E}(1)$?

Of course we can trivially work out some lower bounds, e.g. $\mathscr{E}(1)>{37\over 36}$, but I don't see a way to approach a good exact understanding.

> **Question 2**: Is $\mathscr{E}(q)$ in fact finite for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$?

---

In general, I'm interested in any information about $\mathscr{E}$, or indeed other ways to "count" Egyptian fraction representations. Most of the research I can find is about determining *individual* Egyptian fraction representations which are "optimal" in some sense (e.g. minimal length), which isn't exactly what I'm looking for. (I can't even find any information about the function sending $(q,n)$ to the number of Egyptian fraction representations of $q$ of length $n$.)

Comment: Don't know if it can be made to help, but the coefficient of $Y^qZ^n$ in $\prod_{x=1}^\infty \bigl( 1 + \frac1xZY^{1/x} \bigr)$ equals the sum of $\prod_{x\in X} \frac1x$ over all Egyptian fraction representations of $q$ with exactly $n$ terms. By the way, regarding your last sentence, check the Egyptian fractions section in Guy's *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory*.