# What is known about the average growth rate of the denominators of $n$ Egyptian fractions summing to one?

Tags: reference-request, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds, egyptian-fractions

**Motivation**

In the following question posted both here [on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4479360/weighted-count-of-egyptian-fraction-representations) and over [at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433904/a-weighted-count-of-egyptian-fraction-representations), user Noah Schweber asks about a weighted count on Egyptian fraction representations (EFRs). To that end, he defines the following set of EFRs for a rational number $q$:

$$\mathsf{E}(q)=\left\{X\in[\mathbb{N}]^{\mathit{fin}}: q=\sum_{x\in X}{1\over x}\right\}.$$ Subsequently, he defines the function $$\mathscr{E}\colon q\mapsto \sum_{X\in \mathsf{E}(q)} \left( \prod_{x\in X}{1\over x}\right).$$

Let's call $\mathscr{E}(1)$ the *Egyptian Schweber constant*. Noah himself points out that a lower bound for this constant can be obtained quite easily. For instance, we have $\mathscr{E}(1) > \frac{37}{36}$, as $\mathsf{E}(1)$ contains both $\{1\}$ and $\{2,3,6 \}$.

I am interested in obtaining upper bounds for the Egyptian Schweber constant. Below, I'll outline what I've tried to obtain such a bound.

**Aproach**

My idea of solving this problem is to first use a bound on the amount of possible equation Egyptian fractions of length $n$. To that end, it might be somewhat easier to slightly tweak Schweber's definition to take into account the length of the EFRs: $$\mathsf{E}_{n}(q)=\left\{X_n := \{x_1 , x_2 , \dots , x_n \}: \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x_{k}} = q, \ 0 <x_{1}<x_{2}<\cdots<x_{n} \   \right\}.$$

Then, according to p.8 of the [following paper](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/13_03_Egyptian.pdf) by Ronald Graham we have $$ | \mathsf{E}_{n}(1) | < c_{0}^{(1+\epsilon)2^{n-1}  },  $$ where $c_{0} \approx 1.264. $

Next, we need to obtain a good lower bound for the average size of the denominators of $ \mathsf{E}_{n}(1)$. By definition, it amounts to the sum of the denominators, divided by their amount. Let's call the average size of the denominators $AV(n)$, and the sum $S(n)$. We then have $$AV(n) = S(n)/n. $$

Using the aforementioned source, we also find that $$AV(n) > c_{0}^{-(1+\epsilon)2^{n-1}  } \sum_{X_{n} \in \mathsf{E}_{n}(1)} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{x \in X_{n}} x .$$

Moreover, we then have the following upper bound for the Egyptian Schweber constant: $$ \mathscr{E}(1) < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{0}^{(1+\epsilon)2^{n-1}} \times \left( \frac{1}{AV(n)} \right)^{n} .$$

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any sources on the average size of the denominators of the EFRs. I did find that Sylvester's sequence [can give](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_sequence#Connection_with_Egyptian_fractions) Egyptian fractions of length $n$ with the *largest* denominators. Also, I found the following relevant [master's thesis](https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/90573/Crawford_MB_T_2019.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), but I don't think any bounds for the average size of the EFRs are given in there either.

**Question**

> What is known about the asymptotics (especially lower bounds) of the average size - or the sum - of the denominators of Egyptian fraction representations of one?

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456446/what-is-known-about-the-average-growth-rate-of-the-denominators-of-n-egyptian